# Finding distinct entries associated with existing entry in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table

| Fruit | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| apple | horse |
| apple | human |
| banana | monkey |
| banana | monkey |
| banana | monkey |
| cantaloupe | squirrel |

of (say) fruits and animals and a table

| Fruit | Animals |
| --- | --- |
| apple |  |
| banana |  |
| cantaloupe |  |

of the unique fruits in the first table.

I would like to add a column to the second with a list of the unique animals associated with each fruit, hence

| Fruit | Animals |
| --- | --- |
| apple | horse, human |
| banana | monkey |
| cantaloupe | squirrel |

How can I do this? There is repeated data that I'd like to remove and there can be 1-10 (usually one or two) distinct animals associated with each fruit.

If possible I'd like to avoid VBA/scripting but if that's the only way it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the first table is formatted as a Table and is called FruitAnimal, then the formula for the Animals column is:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(FruitAnimal[Animal],FruitAnimal[Fruit]=[@Fruit]))
```

[image]